Run eventbridge scheduled aws lambda once after cloudformation stack deployment
I am creating a scheduled lambda triggered by an EventBridge Rule with the option suggested here using a cron expression.
I have currently set the cron to trigger every 15mins and that's working fine using the expression
(0/15 * * * ? *)
The lambda after getting created is executing when it hit's the 15mins mark on the clock but I also want the lambda to execute once after creation so I can kick off another process that depends on it immediately.
I experimented with CustomLambdaResource from Cloudformation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudformation.html
and this works fine after creating the Cloudformation stack but during the trigger from EventBridge it's erroring out as there is no ResponseURL provided in the request to send the callback to.
Error message is -
{"errorMessage":"Put \"\": unsupported protocol scheme \"\"","errorType":"Error"}%

Is there any other option to do a first time trigger without having to wait for hitting the 15mins mark ?

so if i understand correctly, you are looking for your lambda function to run after a cloudformation stack has been deployed? so instead of running every 15 mins, you want this to be event driven?

I want one time trigger of the lambda function after deploying cloudformation stack and not wait until the 15min trigger kicks in. Post that it should be triggered every 15mins.
